# How to add a button an ipad app to go to home screen without using the home button

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I am working on this app for iPad. This app disables the home button inorder to force users to use the open app only but not go to other apps or safari. I am trying to add a button on the app which minimizes the app only if the user is a manager. When the application loads, it checks if the user is a manager or not. If the user is a manager, the app will have additional button which says "minimize". So far, I have completed the part which checks if the user is a manager and loads the app with that additional button. My problem came when I try to write the code behind the minimize button.

Is there any efficient and known way (library or method) that I can use to do this task without using the home button?

Comment: you can always kill the app to go to home screen....

Comment: How exactly do you propose to block the home button?

Comment: One way to do this is by sending messages to a MDM server, like Casper Focus (http://www.jamfsoftware.com/software/casper-focus); you could have an administrator login disable single-app mode.  That requires quite a lot of infrastructure though.

Comment: @Xlc The following is an answer for the question "iPad applications, can you minimize ?" on ipad discussion page
"quitting the app by depressing the Home button preserves the app as it was last used. When you open the app up again it open to where your were when you closed the app."

This is exactly what I want my button to do on my app

Comment: you really cant do most (if any) of what you are asking. From your explanation it sounds like you just want to use [device management](http://www.apple.com/iphone/business/it/management.html) to limit the apps users can use.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing this, depending on how you want to app to close.

1. If you want the app to go into the background, and be in the suspended state, use:

   ```
   UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
   [app performSelector:@selector(suspend)];
   ```
2. If you want to completely kill the app (as in it will not be running in the background), use:

   ```
   exit(0);
   ```

   Note killing the app has a "rough" looking effect.  So you may want to combine the two approaches into the following smoother transition:

   ```
   UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
   [app performSelector:@selector(suspend)];  //Put the app into the background

   [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0];   //Pause while the app goes to background

   exit(0);  //Actually kill the app
   ```

Comment: Do not use the exit() function; Apple [explicitly says not to use it](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1561/_index.html), and I've heard anecdotal evidence that they will reject your app for it.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of Apple's doc saying not to use this function (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1561/_index.html); however, this is the best solution to the presented problem.  Further, in order to be rejected for using an inappropriate/restricted method in code, the tester would have to see it implemented.

Comment: The tester doesn't have to 'see' anything - Apple runs heuristics that analyze what frameworks you're linked to, objects being instantiated, and function calls. Also, to create links in a comment, surround the link text with square brackets, followed immediately by the URL in parens.

Comment: You can just make it so that the app does not run in the background.
 So sending it to the background will be the same as killing it